# What does "h" represent in rabin karp algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, rabin-karp

```
t(s+1) = (d*(t(s) -T[s+1]h) + T[s+m+1])mod q
```

`d` is the size of alphabet
`T[1...n]` is the text to be searched
`P[1...m]` is the pattern (m is the size of pattern)
`q` is a prime number

`h = d^m-1 (mod q)` is the value of digit "1" in the higher order position of an m-digit text window.

What does this line mean ? What does `h` represent?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should first look at an easier case where `d` is `10` and the text only contains numbers between `0` and `9`.

`h` is value you use for *shifting left* the high-order digit. For example, let's assume that `m` is `3` and `T = 2345`. From `234`, you can calculate `345` as follows:

```
345 = 10*(234 - 2*100) + 5
```

You can see in this case `h = 100` is used for shifting `2` by 2 digits before subtracting it from `234`. Note that the value of `h` is `h = 103-1`

Now, you can generalize the idea for any `d`, and get `h = dm-1`.

Then, by doing modulo operations, you just add `mod q` every time you calculate any values.